# setRedirectURLToSearchResults() not redirecting

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I an new to NetSuite, and I am having a problem. I have created a button on a form through a user event script.
The button calls a client script, which executes a saved search. The search result should be displayed to the user.

Everything is located in one file:

```
function userEventBeforeLoad_AddSearchButton(type, form, request){
    if(type == 'view' || type == 'edit'){
        form.setScript('customscript_tvg_project_search_button');
        var projectid = nlapiGetFieldValue('companyname');
        form.addButton("custpage_search", "KHM Search", "performSearch('" + projectid + "')");  
    }
}

function performSearch(projectid) {
    console.log('test in client'); 
    alert('projectid = ' + projectid);

    var obj =  nlapiLoadSearch(null, 'customsearch_project_cost_detail_sublist');
    obj.setRedirectURLToSearchResults();
}
```

I created a user event script record for userEventBeforeLoad_AddSearchButton(). and a client script record for performSearch().

In the code above, the button is created and the alert is being displayed. But no redirect is happening.

When I look at the result in Firebug it looks like this:

```
 {"result":"\/app\/common\/search\/searchresults.nl?api=T","id":5}
```

Any ideas why the redirect is not happening, and what to do?

**Edit:** My code above was stripped down to simplify. The reason I am passing *projectid* over is that I actually need to filter the search result, suing the following two lines:

```
var searchFilter = new nlobjSearchFilter('job', null, 'anyof', projectid);
obj.addFilter(searchFilter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3111947.html#bridgehead_N3115348) does state that, "This method is supported in afterSubmit user event scripts, Suitelets, and **client** scripts", it seems from this [NS User Group post](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/suitescript-custom-code/10952-redirect-to-saved-search-results) by a Netsuite Employee in reply to someone who experienced the same issue as you, that the API does not actually perform the redirection client side:

> Redirection works on server side. Use window.location.assign(url) to
>   navigate via script in client-side.

Testing this, I can see that `setRedirectURLToSearchResults` does appear to correctly "load the search into the session", so adding this line afterwards should fix your problem.

```
window.location = '/app/common/search/searchresults.nl?api=T';
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up calling a suitelet to have it redirect to the search result...

Comment: This worked for me in a client script. I used window.open, but my need was to open in a new window. Pop up saved search, manipulate data in-line, close. Perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

setRedirectURLToSearchResults is not working for me either, but since you are using clientscript you might want to try this:

```
function performSearch(projectid) {
    console.log('test in client'); 
    alert('projectid = ' + projectid);

    var searchid = 'customsearch_project_cost_detail_sublist';
    location = '/app/common/search/searchresults.nl?searchid=' + searchid;
}
```

Comment: This should work also work for the OP's query, however if you attempting to build an ad-hoc search via script, or modify an existing search see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40412785/3230114).